# Linux kernel change removed USB compatibility

Tags: 18.04, usb, kernel, external-hdd

For some reason(I think my WiFi was behaving weirdly, flickering on and off), I decided to update my kernel on 18.04.2 to kernel version 4.4.x thinking that it would fix it. The problem still persisted on updating the kernel but it rose another problem: my computer stopped recognizing USB devices: USB drives, external HDDs, none of them are being recognized now. I have tried using `dmesg` to see if any debug message pops up but to no avail. I moved back to the mainline kernel , i.e. `4.15.18-041518-generic` but the problem didn't go away. What can be the reason for this? Am I doing something wrong?